# JavaScript synchronization

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know how I can synchronize next code:

```
javascript: (function() {
    var s2 = document.createElement('script');
    s2.src = 'http://192.168.0.100/jquery.js';
    document.body.appendChild(s2);
    s = document.createElement('link');
    s.rel = "stylesheet";
    s.href = "http://192.168.0.100/1.css";
    s.type = "text/css";
    document.body.appendChild(s);
})();
//var startTime = new Date().getTime();
//while (new Date().getTime() < startTime + 1000);
$(document).ready(function(){
    b="c:\\1.txt";
    var fso, f1; 
    fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    f1 = fso.CreateTextFile(b, true);
    f1.WriteLine("Testing") ;
    document.writeln("File " + b + " is created.");
});
```

When I run this script at first I get an error `SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined`. I think that is because jQuery library is yet no loaded. When I try to run the same script after error's appearencing - it behavior is corect. For synchonization I try to use code that is commented in upper listing. Is works (not always). But I understand that is no strict synchronization (it dependet of concrete situation). How can I use more clever synchronization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that putting in the `script` tag via `appendChild` dhtml method makes it evaluate async. To listen for it getting 'ready' as youre doing it on the document - follow this pattern

```
(function() {
    var s2 = document.createElement('script');
    s2.src = 'http://192.168.0.100/jquery.js';
    document.body.appendChild(s2);
    s2.onload = s2.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(s2.readyState == "complete") $(document).ready(function(){
        b="c:\\1.txt";
        var fso, f1; 
        fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        f1 = fso.CreateTextFile(b, true);
        f1.WriteLine("Testing") ;
        document.writeln("File " + b + " is created.");
      });
    }
    s = document.createElement('link');
    s.rel = "stylesheet";
    s.href = "http://192.168.0.100/1.css";
    s.type = "text/css";
    document.body.appendChild(s);
})();
```

Comment: Are you sure `onreadystatechange` fires on scripts only when the loading has completed? In `XMLHttpRequest` objects, it fires several times going through `readyState`s until it finally gets to `4` when it's done.

Comment: ye, it's pretty but I get SCRIPT5009: 'script' is undefined

Comment: wtf is SCRIPT500009 ugh :) But its a typo on my end, s/script/s2

Answer (score 2):

```
(function($){
  //use $ now

  $(function(){
    //dom ready
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Be sure to load this libary in the footer below the jquery library.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the line with the `$` is being hit when the script tag has been added but before the file has been downloaded.  Normally browsers block while loading JavaScript which prevents this issue, but since you're doing it programatically you don't get the standard synchrony.

Your best bet would be to wait for the script to be loaded.  There's information here:

[Dynamic, cross-browser script loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725272/crossbrowser-script-load-event)

On catching the load event for the completion of the script download.  You can then call your existing `$` ready function as a callback to that event.  I'd suggest using a loader that is made for this stuff, or just use a standard script tag in the DOM unless you have a compelling reason not to.