# Checking if JavaScript is loaded in an Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am adding a JavaScript file to my site (using appendChild) in an Ajax calls oncomplete. After that I am trying to call a function that is included in that file. Like this:

```
// append the JS to the head
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(element);

// call a function that is contained in the js file
myFunction();
```

The call to myFunction says "myFunction() is not defined". The question is, how do I know when it is defined?

Thanks!

Comment: tes if it is not undefined maybe ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725272/dynamic-cross-browser-script-loading

Comment: `typeof(myFunction) === "undefined"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```
if (myfunction != undefined)
{
}
```

Also to make sure it's a function you can add this

```
if(typeof (window.myFunction) == ‘function’) {
```

Comment: Your first example will throw an error if myfunction is undefined. The second one is better :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onload` to find out when it's complete.

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
 s.onreadystatechange = s.onload = function() {
    var state = s.readyState;

    if (!callback.done && (!state || /loaded|complete/.test(state))) {
        // done!
    }
};
s.src = "myurl/myscript.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```

Comment: One word: **IE**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725272/dynamic-cross-browser-script-loading